# MYSQL Only limit results from left table, but show all results from right table

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I am setting up a database which stores posts for a website called "news". Each news post can have some (0-255) media(s) stored with it. I can get all the data like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM news 
LEFT JOIN media ON news.id = news_id
```

Which returns:

| news.id | title | created | media.id | news_id | filename |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Title1 | ... | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | Title2 | ... | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | Title3 | ... | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | Title4 | ... | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | Title5 | ... | 1 | 5 | media1.png |
| 5 | Title5 | ... | 2 | 5 | media2.png |

Notice that `news.id = 5` shows up for twice since it has two images associated with it.

My goal is to get the latest 3 posts like so

```
SELECT * 
FROM news 
LEFT JOIN media ON news.id = news_id 
ORDER BY created DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Which returns:

| news.id | title | created | media.id | news_id | filename |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Title5 | ... | 2 | 5 | media2.png |
| 5 | Title5 | ... | 1 | 5 | media1.png |
| 4 | Title4 | ... | NULL | NULL | NULL |

However I would like it to return all the posts with ids 5, 4, and 3 along with all their media like so:

| news.id | title | created | media.id | news_id | filename |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Title5 | ... | 2 | 5 | media2.png |
| 5 | Title5 | ... | 1 | 5 | media1.png |
| 4 | Title4 | ... | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | Title3 | ... | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Is this possible with MySql or is there some other database organization that can accomplish this? Basically I would like to only limit the results from the LEFT table and let the "repeats" show up so I can still get all the RIGHT table data. I am using PHP prepared statements to make these MYSQL queries so I may not be able to use subquery but I am not sure.

Comment: A prepared statement does not limit your ability to use a subquery, should you choose to do so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select from a subquery that gets the last 3 posts, rather than the whole table.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM news
    ORDER BY created DESC
    LIMIT 3
) AS news
LEFT JOIN media ON news.id = news_id
```